# get dynamic rows data values to prefill the forms using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table in which the rows are dynamic and the values come from database.

for eg my table is as follows:-

```
name|email
xyz|xyz@gmail.com 
pqr|pqr@gmail.com
```

I have kept the names as link on clicking of which a form opens below with the same field as of table i.e

name:----
email: ----

so now what i want is with opening of the form i also want that the form should get prefilled with values that are there in table ..

for eg:- if a user clicks pqr then a form should get opend with values in it..

```
name : pqr
email : pqr@gmail.com
```

I made a javascript function where i pass the userid of the username that the user clicks..and in that i function i did the following :

```
    var id=userid;

    var row = document.getElementById(id);

    var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName("td");

    document.getElementById("fname").value = inputs[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("email").value = inputs[1].innerHTML;
```

and as i am using

```
inputs[0].innerHTML;
```

it prints the name like this :

```
<font size="4"><a href="#" id="viewUser" onclick="populate('73');">xyz</a></font>
```

but I want only 'xyz' in my textbox..for that when I did :

```
inputs[0].value;
```

it gave me its value as undefined...why is it so?

please someone guide on getting the form filled with values of the row.

Comment: What are you using to populate the rows of the table?

Comment: I have set a user object in request ..through that i get these table values

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific, are you using JavaScript to get the data and create the table?

Comment: no no..just ran a simple for loop..i mean created rows inside for loop

Comment: Would the user start typing in their name & have an auto-complete prompt? Or would the user be selecting a name from a drop-down list?

Comment: As i mentioned in the table the names of the user is hyperlink..on click of that form should be displayd and prefilled with that user values

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here. See this fiddle for working code: http://jsfiddle.net/G6Q5X/

Here's a basic table.

```
<table id="list">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Name 1</a></td>
        <td>Email 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Name 2</a></td>
        <td>Email 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

First you want to get the table by ID and get the rows that it contains:

```
//nodeList of all rows in the table
var table = document.getElementById('list').children[0].children;
```

Then add an event listener to each link:

```
for(var i=0, len=table.length; i<len; i++){
    var link = table[i].children[0].children[0]; 
    link.addEventListener('click', getInfo);
}
```

The callback for the event listener will call a function, I used one I called "getInfo":

```
var getInfo = function(){
    var name = this.innerHTML;
    var email = this.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML;
    alert('Your name is: ' + name + ' and email is: ' + email)
}
```

I hope this helps.